# What is a better way to solve this exercise?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python - and programming - and was given this exercise. I'm able to get the expected result with the code below, but was wondering what other ways there are to solve this using Python 3.x.

The exercise is to take a number and generate the following pattern:

User input: 1

```
X
```

User input: 2

```
O O O
O X O
O O O
```

User Input: 3

```
X X X X X
X O O O X
X O X O X
X O O O X
X X X X X
```

and so on...

Here is what I have:

```
def makePattern():
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    def makeBoxes(num):
        width = (num * 2) - 1
        midpoint = num - 1
        matrix = [ [ "X" for i in range(width) ] for j in range(width) ]
        for d1 in range(width):
            mpD1 = abs(midpoint - d1)
            for d2 in range(width):
                mpD2 = abs(midpoint - d2)
                if (mpD1 % 2 == 1):
                    if mpD2 <= mpD1:
                        matrix[d1][d2] = "O"
                if (mpD2 % 2 == 1):
                    if mpD1 <= mpD2:
                        matrix[d1][d2] = "O"
        printBoxes(matrix,width)
        makePattern()
    def printBoxes(matrix,width):
        holder = ""
        count = 1
        for row in matrix:
            for point in row:
                holder += (point + " ")
                if count % width == 0:
                    print(holder)
                    holder = ""
                count += 1
    makeBoxes(num)
makePattern()
```

Comment: to accomplish _what_ exactly?

Comment: If you can be more specific about what you're trying to improve, this might have a home on [CodeReview.SE] (or _maybe_ [CodeGolf.SE]). It's really not clear what your problem is, and I don't think that SO is the right place for this question.

Comment: Since you have working code, make sure you keep a copy of that version.  Then just try and simplify it step by step until you have something nicer.  You can learn a lot that way.  BTW if your question is "Can people on S.O. do  my homework better?" then the answer is "probably yes" - but you probably want a more specific question.

Comment: Hint: `"XO"[0] == "X"`, and `"XO"[1] == "O"`.  In your list comprehension for matrix, instead of `"X"`, you could use `"XO"[something]`, where "something" turns the coordinates `i,j` into either 0 or 1.  Try playing with a function of `mpD1` and `mpD2` to see if you can figure out what it should be.  (Equivalently, you could do `"X" if something else "O"`.  The important part is spotting how the Xs and Os depend upon i and j.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to print a board with a specific pattern. Without further description it would be hard to say more.

Some specific comments about your usage of python:

- Overall it feels a unpythonic. It is too verbose. Avoid camel casing.
- There is too much repetitive logic. Width seems unnecesary in printBoxes
- printBoxes could be a lot better. Research what `" ".join(row)` does. Knowing that, in python 3 printBoxes should be a simple one line list comprehension.

Some specific comments about your algorithm:

- I can think of a couple of algorithms that are much simpler than yours, given a position matrix[i][j] you know if it needs to be an 'X' or an 'O' also in a one liner.

If you put it all together this could generating the list should be one line of python and printing it should be another. Ironically this should also increase the readability of your code.